# Ergo - Unable to Parse ReducedTransaction, getting Not enough bytes in buffer

Tags: ergoscript

If we have a reducedTxBytes as String form. How can we sign it via appkit? (I found that we can use

```
ctx.parseReducedTransaction
```

, however i'm getting this

```
requirement failed: Not enough bytes in the buffer
```

I'm doing:

```
      {
        (Address.create(tx._1),
          client.getContext.parseReducedTransaction(tx._2.getBytes))
      }

Where tx = (String, String) representing (WalletAddress, ReducedTxBytes)
```

For a sample tx like this:

```
3QIB_1JG5qTPntBexsiCikbQ_VE1uhtoBG5TyWttASKOkosAAAADg2FcoBCWIDoj4kbTFy2D_mMHmGvdRZRldiDJ0oWk0Dd85dhG5-wa8gfLDadilJjVz2_6zXtNKNCNzZXYicp3OvZjSvkKhjvNecY0PlaLGyzdPOvyMDYaEu87_luDcOdgA4CJegAIzQPULJZ0Jd77AX3zyVjLnTHR3SrYxe50EA_yE0yvp85wP62ZNAABBRTAhD0QBQQABAAONhACBKALCM0Ceb5mfvncu6xVoGKVzocLBwKb_NstzijZWfKBWxb4F5jqAtGSo5qMx6cBcwBzARABAgQC0ZaDAwGTo4zHsqVzAAABk8KypXMBAHRzAnMDgwEIze6sk7GlcwStmTQAAMC71dUEAAjNA9QslnQl3vsBffPJWMudMdHdKtjF7nQQD_ITTK-nznA_rZk0AwABAb_ckOgBAgEAzQPULJZ0Jd77AX3zyVjLnTHR3SrYxe50EA_yE0yvp85wP51P8Gw=
```

While trying to debug I found that the reason why it failed is due to decoding. As its a string that was encoded from an array bytes, it has to be decoded the same way.

Here is the way it was encoded:

```
reducedTx = Base64.getUrlEncoder.encodeToString(reducedTx.toBytes)
```

Where reducedTx is a ReducedTransaction

Answer below

Comment: What is `tx._2.getBytes`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens due to a failure of decoding it to the right bytes. Because it is being encoded via Base64.GetUrlEncoder, it has to be decoded the same way. Therefore this line down here works:

```
        val result = (Address.create(tx._1),
          client.getContext.parseReducedTransaction(
            Base64.getUrlDecoder.decode(tx._2)))
```

Note that we're using Base64.getUrlDecoded rather than getBytes.